# How to use omit with Ansible and avoid any errors?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I tried to use omit with an expression like this:

```
id: "{{ openstack_networks.id | default(omit) }}"
```

But it seems that it keeps failing with an exception when `openstack_networks` variable is not defined.

What is the correct way to write this jinja2 filter?

I want to omit the parameter in case openstack_networks.id does not exists.

Comment: I was trying to get my head around why an existing ansible playbook was using `some.thing | default() or omit` instead of simply `some.thing | default( omit )` and ended up here. However, best as I can tell, ansible 7 appears to happily accept the latter incantation now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not super elegant, but 100% working solution to handle keys of possibly undefined parent dicts:

```
id: "{{ (openstack_networks | default({})).id | default(omit) }}"
```

This will give you `omit` if `openstack_networks` is defined but has no `id` key or if `openstack_networks` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Now my head hurts! There is no beauty in Ansible :(

Comment: First time I've seen that construct, and I think it's elegant. My use case isn't necessarily for an omit, but I've run into a lot of problems that this would solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Interestingly enough, Ansible will take something that reads like plain English:

```
id: "{{ omit if openstack_networks.id is not defined else openstack_networks.id }}"
```

The benefit here is that there are no additional parentheses.