# Ansible looping when a variable has no value

Tags: ansible

I have created a variable to disable sites in nginx within my main set of tasks. Since this is a one time task, meaning once domain1.com is disabled I can comment the entire line out. When I do, I receive an error

*" {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'None' has no attribute 'domain'".*

What can I do to modify my task to only run when there are domains listed within the variable?

```
nginx_sites_disabled:
#- domain: "domain1.com"

- name: Disable sites
    file:
    path: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{ item.domain }}
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{nginx_sites_disabled}}"
  notify:
  - Reload nginx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `default` filter within your task:

```
- name: Disable sites
    file:
    path: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{ item.domain }}
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ nginx_sites_disabled | default([]) }}"
  notify:
    - Reload nginx
```

Related answer: [Ansible: apply when to complete loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491293/ansible-apply-when-to-complete-loop/42491559#42491559)

Comment: When I apply this filter, the sites-enabled folder gets deleted.

Comment: @GreenLion not in case of my answer. In this case if you pass empty list to with_items, the loop will be skipped.

Comment: How should the list nginx_sites_disabled look like using your example? nginx_sites_disabled:[]?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to comment out the lines when the work is done.

Like most of Ansible modules, `file` module is [idempotent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/glossary.html#term-idempotency) : if the desired `state` is `absent` and the file isn't there, it won't do anything.

Just leave `nginx_sites_disabled` list unchanged.

By the way, if you still need `nginx_sites_disabled` to be an empty list, you need to write this :

```
---
nginx_sites_disabled: []
```

otherwise, `nginx_sites_disabled` will be equal to `None`. That's why you have this error.